# Invalid Bukkit command | YML Error catch with valid YML

Tags: java, bukkit

So I have double and triple checked my YML and ran it through a validator. My plugins load up fine, I can create a hello world command within my Main class that works. However upon using a second .java file with a second command it continuously displays my YML usage text.

Main.java

```
package lordfluffyjr.TarrenCraft.jEssentialsX.commandSrc;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener { //Extending JavaPlugin so that Bukkit 
knows its the main class

//Housekeeping
Logger jEssentialsXLogger = Bukkit.getLogger();

@Override
public void onEnable(){//  Where plugins will be loaded.
    PluginManager manager = getServer().getPluginManager();
    manager.registerEvents(this, this);
    Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("jEssentialsX has been enabled!");
    
    //Enable FAQ
    manager.registerEvents(new Faq(), this);
    Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("FAQ has been enabled!");

}

@Override
public void onDisable(){//  Where plugins will be disabled.
    jEssentialsXLogger.info("Test 1 has been disabled!");
    jEssentialsXLogger.severe("Test 1 has an error and has not loaded.");  
    }
}
```

Faq.java

```
package lordfluffyjr.TarrenCraft.jEssentialsX.commandSrc;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class Faq implements Listener, CommandExecutor{

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
{
    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("faq")) {
        sender.sendMessage("Welcome to our FAQ!");
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

plugin.yml

```
main: lordfluffyjr.TarrenCraft.jEssentialsX.commandSrc.Main
name: jEssentialsX
version: 0.1
author: LordFluffyJr
api-version: 1.16
commands:
  faq:
    description: A list of our frequently asked questions plugin description!
    usage: Syntax error! Use [/faq <topic> <page number>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not registering the Faq class as the command executor. You need to set it with

```
Bukkit.getPluginCommand("faq").setExecutor(- Faq class instance-);
```